# geth.ipc is generated while initialising genesis.json file for private net

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I am trying to create a Privatenet in custom folder...But initialising **genesis.json** file using below command:

> geth –datadir =/home/kottackal/Documents/project1 init genesis.json

the **geth.ipc** file is generated in **.ethereum** folder instead of getting an output **successfully wrote genesis state**

**genesis.json**

```
{
"config": {
"chainId": 2340,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0
 },
"alloc": {
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {"balance": 
"111111111"},
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": {"balance": "222222222"}
 },
"coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
"difficulty" : "0x20000",
"extraData"  : "",
"gasLimit"   : "0x8880000",
"nonce"      : "0x0000000000000042",
"mixhash"    : 
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"parentHash" : 
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp"  : "0x00"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the answer...we have to specify the correct path of genesis.json...

```
geth –datadir =/home/kottackal/Documents/project1 init /home/kottackal/Documents/project1/genesis.json
```